# Azure Location not allowed by Snowflake Integration even though the location is not blocked

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am ingesting data from IBMi system to Snowflake through Azure Data factory.

On the snowflake side I have an integration which has list of allowed storage locations and it has the Azure location which I am using.

However I am getting error:
SQL compilation error: Location  is not allowed by integration . Please use DESC INTEGRATION to check out allowed and blocked locations.

Could anyone suggest why I am getting this.

P.S: This was working for a long time. It started not working since last Friday.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show the output for desc integration highlighting the storage being listed and the error message seen for review?

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to test using * wildcard in storage_allowed_locations, meaning “allow access to all buckets and/or paths”. Ref: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-storage-integration.html

Example:

```
 create storage integration azure_int
 type = external_stage
 storage_provider = azure
 enabled = true
 azure_tenant_id = 'a123b4c5-1234-123a-a12b-1a23b45678c9'
 storage_allowed_locations = ('*')
 storage_blocked_locations = 
 ('azure://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/path3/', 
 'azure://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/path4/');
```